# File/Folder Handling in Android

Tags: android

I try to create folder in android app, that folder used only in 
application in which its create that folder. Can this is possible or is 
there any folder (already provided by android ) which work like this. 
Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
context.getCacheDir();
```

**Note: you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you; you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space.**

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) for more information.